# Finding index common in two numpy arrays matching certain condition

Tags: python, numpy

I have following two numpy arrays:

```
>>> k1 = np.array([[1,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[1,0,0],[0,0,0]])
>>> k1
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]])

>>> k2 = np.array(list(itertools.permutations([1,2,3])))
>>> k2
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 3, 2],
       [2, 1, 3],
       [2, 3, 1],
       [3, 1, 2],
       [3, 2, 1]])
```

I want to find that dimension-1 index for which k2 contain 3 and k1 contains 1. For example, here `k2[4,0]==3` and `k1[4,0]==1`. So I want to return 0 here.

I will also like to return list of dimesion-1 indices for multiple such occurrences. How I do this?

I tried following:

```
>>> k1 == 1
array([[ True, False, False],
       [False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False],
       [False, False, False]])

>>> k2 == 3
array([[False, False,  True],
       [False,  True, False],
       [False, False,  True],
       [False,  True, False],
       [ True, False, False],
       [ True, False, False]])
```

I am unable to proceed from this. This is what I tried next, but its nothing useful.

```
>>> (k1==1) == (k2==3)
array([[False,  True, False],
       [ True, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False],
       [ True, False,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [False,  True,  True]])
```

I also tried this:

```
>>> np.where(k1==1)
(array([0, 1, 4], dtype=int64), array([0, 2, 0], dtype=int64))
>>> np.where(k2==3)
(array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], dtype=int64), array([2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0], dtype=int64))
```

Somehow, I have to first take `(4,0)` out of both of these and then return 0 from it. But how do I do it?

Is there any other better/smaller numpythonic way for this?

Comment: are you looking for a row that has 1 and 3 at any position, or a single cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got very close with your first approach. But instead of doing `(k1==1) == (k2==3)`, do `(k1==1) & (k2==3)`:

```py
>>> (k1==1) & (k2==3)
array([[False, False, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False],
       [False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

From this, you can easily use `where` to find the indices you are after:

```py
>>> np.where((k1==1) & (k2==3))
(array([4]), array([0]))
```

The second element in that output will be an array of indices in dimension-1 where your condition is met.

Comment: ohh I even tried `(k1==1) and (k2==3)`, but gave me `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`. Seems that I have to use `&`

Comment: Yeah `and` always returns a single bool (likewise with `or`), whereas `&` is an operator that can return whatever - for a numpy array, it performs an element-wise 'and' operation and returns an array (and similarly with `|`)